# Primefaces template - south position doesn/t work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've got following problem. When I set  everything works just fine. However I want to have margins from top, left and right so I set fullPage to false. Then layoutUnit with id 'south' (and south position as well) is displayed at the top of the page. Tried to fix it, but without effects.

Here's code of my template:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>#{msg['Title']}</title>
<f:metadata>
    <ui:insert name="metadata" />
</f:metadata>

<h:head>


<h:head>



<p:layout fullPage="false" style="margin: 2em !important;">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" id="north" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" header="#{msg['menuTitle']}" style="height:500px;overflow:hidden;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;" size="225">
        <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit styleClass="styleOrange" position="center" style="padding:20px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;">
        <h:form id="mainForm">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="msgs" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="south" resizable="false" id="south" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>


</h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="statusDialog.hide();">
</h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except center layoutUnit, other layout units must have dimensions defined via size option. Try adding it to the south unit

Comment: I guess this problem relates to the fullPage="false/true" if you do fullPage="false", south position doesn't appear.But if you select "true",problem solved.

Comment: Yes, and `false` is the default so this is probably a common layout gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

The footer is out of the view scope without a size. The center layoutUnit takes all the space. Try changing fullPage attribute of the layout element to true and you will see the footer.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true" style="margin: 2em !important;">
```